# Unable to click on 'OK' button in the web alert

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, icloud-drive

Am trying to click on 'OK' button in the attached popup using selenium webdriver alert interface.[image]

When I inspected the 'OK button using accessibility inspector, it has shown the below properties.

```
target.processes()["Google Chrome"].frontWindow().images()["Chrome critical alert"].click()
target.processes()["Google Chrome"].frontWindow().buttons()["OK"].click()
```

So, I have tried webdriver alert to click on 'OK', but it didnt work.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.accept();
```

Have spent enough time on this but couldnt find a solution.Appreciate any help here !

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a browser "alert" box to me, so the Alert method won't find it. It also doesn't look like a "popup" (a separate desktop window) in the usual sense. I'm guessing from your description that it's a conventional HTML element on the page. Therefore, you need to find the OK button by usual Selenium element-finding techniques and then click() on the element.